# JAVA End Of File multiple lines input

Tags: java, while-loop, jvm, eof, uppercase

When I run the code for this program I get:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Capital {
     public static void main(String []args) {

        Scanner kbd  = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (kbd.hasNextLine()) {
        String str = kbd.nextLine();

        System.out.println(str.toUpperCase());

        }
     }
 }
```

the output for each input, for example

```
input: abc
output:ABC
input: xyz
output:XYZ
```

How do I set up the program to allow multiple lines to be entered before declaring end of file?  like :

```
input: abc
       xyz
       aaa 
       ...etc

output: ABC
        XYZ
        AAA
        ...etc
```

I have a feeling I'm gonna be embarrassed when I find out!

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: You are not taking input from file . Then how can you verify whether you have reached EOF or not ?

Comment: Try ctrl-z as last input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the output only at the end, so I suggest storing the input somewhere e.g. a List, and only printing them out when the end of the input is reached.

```
Scanner kbd  = new Scanner(System.in);

List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
while (kbd.hasNextLine())
    input.add(kbd.nextLine());

// after all the input, output the results.
for (String str : input)
    System.out.println(str.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class EndOfFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n = 1;
    String line;
    while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(n + " " + line);
        n++;
    }

   }
}
```